# Change of latitude and longitude when rotating around an Euler pole

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates, latitude-longitude, spherical-geometry, rotate

Suppose we have a point P on the surface of the Earth characterized by its latitude and longitude. There is an Euler pole given together with an angle of rotation around the axis associated with this Euler pole.

How do I calculate the **change** in latitude and longitude of P that results from this rotation? I would like to avoid converting to geocentric coordinates to avoid numerical errors due to conversions.

Comment: Geodesic computation is good to a few millimeters, probably better than you'd get from a local projection.

Comment: Would you be so kind to provide any links to the relevant methods?

Comment: [Edit] the question to specify a chosen GIS library, and provide code for what you've attempted, and what error you've encountered, and then we'll have an answerable question. There are no easy answers to the partial differential equation which is the Forward (aka Direct) Problem of Geodesy.